# Copyright - okay to change open sourced Maven groupId?

Tags: maven

There is an opensourced Maven plugin hosted on github and I would like to use it. However, I needed to make a little adjustment in it specific for my needs and so I need to deploy it to our company's Maven repo.

The repo serves as a proxy to Maven Central and other and I want to avoid conflicts so I thought I would change the groupId/artifactId to something else. Is that okay, copyright and ethics-wise? I will leave credit to the original, links etc. The license is Apache 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: Copyright-wise, that would depend on specificity of that library (and this is off-topic here). But assuming you are allowed to, then YES!, change the Maven coordinates and give attribution to the original, otherwise you'll eat your hat in the future with the conflicts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Open Source Stack Exchange](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) (the question is about licensing).

Comment: Which plugin you are talking about?